# Using sudo in Git Extensions when pushing changes to remote Linux repo

Tags: git, sudo, git-extensions

I have Git Extensions v3.1.1 installed in Windows 7 Pro.

Rephrased my problem description:
Remote GIT repo is Debian Linux, I connect to it with myuser which has sudo permission.
The /etc directory is on this remote Linux system, having root:root owner.
Local GIT repo is on Windows 7 Pro, where the Git Extensions is installed.

I don't get root permission for the remote Linux server, just sudo for myuser. But myuser is not allowed to modify /etc directory content of remote Linux repo, because /etc directory is owned by root:root. My problem is with pushing the changes to the remote Linux repo.

I would need to use sudo because the etckeeper installed on remote Linux needs root or sudo for /etc directory (which is owned by root).

If I connect remote Linux repo with myuser, pushing the changes to /etc is denied because the /etc owner is root:root.

How can I push changes to /etc as root, while I was connected to remote Linux repo as myuser (which has sudo permission added)?

Comment: What do you mean by sudo its "windows"

Comment: @YedidyaRashi Remote GIT repo is on Debian Linux.

Comment: @klor: why should that matter? Files are simply stored there, what commands you execute locally shouldn't matter to the remote. Is there a *specific* problem that you are trying to solve, because as vague as it is righ tnow it feel unsolvable.

Comment: I don't get root permission for the remote Linux, just sudo. But myuser is not allowed to modify /etc directory content of remote Linux repo. My problem is with pushing the changes to the remote Linux repo.

Comment: The `sudo` command *must be run on the remote system*. Having a sudo extension on the Windows system would be useless. Git won't run sudo for you, so if you're using your local machine to invoke Git on the remote system, you literally *can't* get it to invoke sudo there ... and if you're using your local machine to invoke Git commands on the local machine, there's no point to attempting sudo, since it won't help.

Comment: In short, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you need is a way to install your favorite GUI on the other system, and then a remote-desktop (RDP or similar) program so that you can *run on that system* from your local Windows system.

Comment: Rephrased the OP

Comment: Why is your git repository position in `/etc/` in the first place? That's a **terrible** place for a git repository. It should be in a place that you *can* write to.

Comment: @JoachimSauer There is a software named etckeeper, which keeps tracking of system changes done in /etc. It uses git internally.

Comment: @klor: I think "internally" is the key word here. I've had a quick look through its documentation and **nothing** in there suggests that you're ever meant to actually *push* to that git repository. etckeeper apparently exists to a large degree *because* git (and most other VCS) are not fully equippped to handle the complexity of tracking `/etc/` (mostly permission issues). I think the "proper" way to do changes to `/etc` remotely is to ssh in, `sudo whatevercommandtoeditetc` followed by `sudo etckeeper commit`.